# Show page content based on php array

Tags: php, arrays, redirect, show-hide

We have an array of some user ID's that will have access to a page. If the user is in the array we want to show the page. IF the user is not in the array we want to either echo out Not Valid ID, or redirect them to a different page.

```
<?php

$valid = array("aa123", "aa34", "bb12");
$id = "pp123";
if (in_array($id, $valid)) {
    echo "Valid ID";
}

else {
    echo "Not Valid, go away";
}

?>

<div id="the-page">The main content</div>
```

This is working no problem (the ID will be pulled in via our Central Authentication System, but I am hard coding it here for purposes of the demo). We want to show the content on the page if the ID is in the array, if not either don't show the content OR redirect them. Is there a way to achieve this without a css display none?

Any ideas or thoughts would he very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the else block use `header('Location: invalid.php'); exit;` perhaps?

Comment: It looks like this is in the middle of a page. You should do this first thing on the page, prior to output so `header` can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$valid = array("aa123", "aa34", "bb12");
$id = "pp123";
if (!in_array($id, $valid)) {
    exit("Not Valid, go away");
}
?>

<div id="the-page">The main content</div>
```

Or if you want to redirect to some other file then do this

```
<?php

$valid = array("aa123", "aa34", "bb12");
$id = "pp123";
if (!in_array($id, $valid)) {
    header('Location: filename.php');
    exit();
}
?>

<div id="the-page">The main content</div>
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Thanks for everyone's input. I went with an echo instead of a redirect, but added the exit so the page would stop. So the header and message of not available was visible.